Search for multiple exact HTTP paths and methods
I'm trying to filter records based on multiple HTTP paths and methods, such as /api/v1/users with GET and /api/v1/product with POST for a specific CallerId. However, with the current query I'm using, I'm only retrieving records for one path.
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "data.Identity.CallerId": "9C51E5FC-761E-4D54-82B9-6D41C9189307"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "match_phrase": {
                                                "data.RequestInfo.Path": "/api/v1/product"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match_phrase": {
                                                "data.RequestInfo.HttpMethod": "POST"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "match_phrase": {
                                                "data.RequestInfo.Path": "/api/v1/users"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match_phrase": {
                                                "data.RequestInfo.HttpMethod": "GET"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
}```


The query you have just works fine. Maybe because of the size: 10 the only result you see related to some specific path like data.RequestInfo.Path.keyword. Check the following example.
POST _bulk
{ "index": { "_index": "http_requests", "_id": "1" } }
{ "data": { "Identity": { "CallerId": "9C51E5FC-761E-4D54-82B9-6D41C9189307" }, "RequestInfo": { "Path": "/api/v1/users", "HttpMethod": "GET" } } }
{ "index": { "_index": "http_requests", "_id": "2" } }
{ "data": { "Identity": { "CallerId": "9C51E5FC-761E-4D54-82B9-6D41C9189307" }, "RequestInfo": { "Path": "/api/v1/product", "HttpMethod": "POST" } } }
{ "index": { "_index": "http_requests", "_id": "3" } }
{ "data": { "Identity": { "CallerId": "9C51E5FC-761E-4D54-82B9-6D41C9189307" }, "RequestInfo": { "Path": "/api/v1/orders", "HttpMethod": "POST" } } }


GET http_requests/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "data.Identity.CallerId": "9C51E5FC-761E-4D54-82B9-6D41C9189307"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "data.RequestInfo.Path": "/api/v1/product"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "data.RequestInfo.HttpMethod": "POST"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "data.RequestInfo.Path": "/api/v1/users"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "data.RequestInfo.HttpMethod": "GET"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.RequestInfo.Path.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}


